# How to speed up the tomcat starting process in gradle?

Tags: gradle, tomcat7, build.gradle

Trying to start tomcat using this gradle code snippet

```
task startTomcat(type:Exec) {
    workingDir tomcat_home + "\\bin"
    commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'startup.bat'
}
```

After run this task tomcat is starting but gradle build process is hanged(waiting). How to solve this problem?

Comment: Isn't it hanged till tomcat is running?

Comment: Yes mate. gradle task hanged till tomcat running

Comment: So this is expected behavior. Nothing can be solved here.

Comment: Is there are any method to run this task in background and move to next task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this task in background but it will be maybe not difficult but problematic to keep control of the running process (e.g. stopping it on demand - which might be solved by adding `stopTomcat` task). What You need is the following piece of code:

```
task startTomcat << {
   def processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(['cmd','/c','startup.bat'])
   processBuilder.directory(new File("$tomcat_home\\bin"))
   processBuilder.start()
}
```

I don't guarantee that this will work as is because I don't have any windows workstation to try it out, but this is the code that should do the job after (maybe required) some altering.